# Eager load only if relationship exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have a morph relationship, where the subject could have multiple relationships. Their existence depends on morphed model. I need to retrieve all the related models (`whereHas()` doesn't solve the problem) and I want their relationships being loaded if they exists on particular model (`with()` won't work, because the relationship doesn't always exist).

Is there anything else (built-in) that I can use to fluently solve this scenario, or hacking is the only way around it?

```
<?php

...

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the post's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }

    /**
     * This relationship is available for Post model only
     */
    public function relationA()
    {
        // return $this->hasMany(...);
    }
}

class Video extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the video's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }

    /**
     * This relationship is available for Video model only
     */
    public function relationB()
    {
        // return $this->hasMany(...);
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning commentable models.
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public static function feed()
    {
        self::with('commentable')
            ->withIfExists(['commentable.relationA', 'commentable.relationB'])
            // ...
            ->get();
    }

    public function scopeWithIfExists($query, $relation)
    {
        // There is no way to implement such a scope
        // in order to reduce umber of queries by eager loading relations
        // as we don't know of what type the subject is
        // without looking it up in database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out at [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes).

With that you can create a scope to load a relation if it exists, for example:

```
User::withRelationIfExists('cars')->where(...)
```

For example: (code not tested)

```
public function scopeWithRelationIfExists($query, $relation)
{
    if (! method_exists(get_class(), $relation)) {
        return;
    }

    return $query->with($relation);
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't fix it in my opinion. It either does load it or not, but for all. So you either have the relation defined on the current model and laravel will eager load it or not, and it won't be loaded for any. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This method is a custom helper to easily load the relation without checking it all the time. If you want to use it you need to declare that method in the Model, or create a Parent model to inherit, or add it in a Trait and use it in the models you want this custom scope. There's no way to tell Laravel to load relations automatically if you don't know the name of the relation.

Comment: I understand scopes, and I started implementing it the way you suggest, but in one point I realized it doesn't make sense, because if you have morphMany relation, the class of the object is being stored in the database (because there could be various types, right), so you can't check if there is such a relation before you query db, which is where it all breaks.

Comment: I added some code, so you can better understand what I am talking about

Comment: As I see it, polymorphic relations make you able to load a model or another from the  database field `commentable_type` and `commentable_id` for example. But you still need the relation `public function commentable()` declared.